# Maven JBoss plugin update from 1.3.1 to 1.3.2 caused deployment to fail

Tags: deployment, maven-2, jboss, maven-plugin

By accident I updated Maven JBoss plugin to version 1.3.2. After that the deployment failed silently, no attempt to connect JBoss was made. Eventually we found out the version change and reverted back to old version.

Here is the current config:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <serverName>default</serverName>
                <hostName>localhost</hostName>
                <port>8080</port>
                <deployUrlPath>
                    /jmx-console/HtmlAdaptor?action=invokeOpByName&amp;name=jboss.system:service%3DMainDeployer&amp;methodName=redeploy&amp;argType=java.net.URL&amp;arg0=
                </deployUrlPath>
                <undeployUrlPath>
                    /jmx-console/HtmlAdaptor?action=invokeOpByName&amp;name=jboss.system:service%3DMainDeployer&amp;methodName=undeploy&amp;argType=java.net.URL&amp;arg0=
                </undeployUrlPath>
                <fileName>
                    ${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}
                </fileName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

... and...

```
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <fileName>${basedir}/target/${application.name}.ear</fileName>
                        <server>jBoss</server>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>deploy</id>
                            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>deploy</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
```

I went through the change list of the plugin but I did not spot any configuration changes. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `mvn jboss:deploy` with the `-X` option shows that the version 1.3.2 of the Maven 2.x JBoss plugin doesn't read the `fileName` anymore:

```
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.codehaus.mojo:jboss-maven-plugin:1.3.2:deploy' -->
[DEBUG]   (f) deployUrlPath = /jmx-console/HtmlAdaptor?action=invokeOpByName&name=jboss.system:service%3DMainDeployer&methodName=deploy&argType=java.net.URL&arg0=
[DEBUG]   (f) fileNameEncoding = UTF-8
[DEBUG]   (f) hostName = localhost
[DEBUG]   (f) port = 8080
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
```

Since version 1.3.2, the Maven 2.x JBoss Plugin is able to deploy a **List** of files so you need to configure it like this:

```
<fileNames>
  <fileName>
  ${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}
  </fileName>
</fileNames>
```

And this time, the deployment succeeds as shown by the new output of `mvn jboss:deploy -X`:

```
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.codehaus.mojo:jboss-maven-plugin:1.3.2:deploy' -->
[DEBUG]   (f) deployUrlPath = /jmx-console/HtmlAdaptor?action=invokeOpByName&name=jboss.system:service%3DMainDeployer&methodName=deploy&argType=java.net.URL&arg0=
[DEBUG]   (f) fileNameEncoding = UTF-8
[DEBUG]   (f) fileNames = [/home/pascal/Projects/q1366663/target/q1366663.war]
[DEBUG]   (f) hostName = localhost
[DEBUG]   (f) port = 8080
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[INFO] [jboss:deploy {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] Deploying %2Fhome%2Fpascal%2FProjects%2Fq1366663%2Ftarget%2Fq1366663.war to JBoss.
[DEBUG] url = http://localhost:8080/jmx-console/HtmlAdaptor?action=invokeOpByName&name=jboss.system:service%3DMainDeployer&methodName=deploy&argType=java.net.URL&arg0=%2Fhome%2Fpascal%2FProjects%2Fq1366663%2Ftarget%2Fq1366663.war
```

This change is due to [MJBOSS-11](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MJBOSS-11) (fixed in the change set [4282](http://fisheye.codehaus.org/changelog/mojo/?cs=4282)) which doesn't have any *"Fix Version/s"* and thus doesn't appear in the release notes (which is bad).